# Error after deploying asp.net core app to azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core

After deploying my asp.net core app to azure for the first time and ran it, I got the following error:

> Error. An error occurred while processing your request. Development
>   Mode Swapping to Development environment will display more detailed
>   information about the error that occurred.
>
> Development environment should not be enabled in deployed
>   applications, as it can result in sensitive information from
>   exceptions being displayed to end users. For local debugging,
>   development environment can be enabled by setting the
>   ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable to Development, and
>   restarting the application.

Please note that I tried debug and release mode when publishing in visual studio and I made sure that I chose the default migration and have the connection string as well.
If possible, can you tell me how to enable development mode as shown or explain the error further?
Thank you

Edit: As per the suggestion I received I found the following in cloud explorer log:

> Msvsmon was unable to start a server named '127.0.0.1:50867'. The
>   following error occurred: An instance of the remote debugger is
>   already running on this computer, or another process is already bound
>   to the specified TCP/IP port.

Comment: 1. do you get the error **while** deploying or **after**. The title doesn't really match what you write in the body 2. do you run a self-contained or portable app? Usually it takes a few days or weeks until the Azure instances get an updated version of the runtime. Considering it was released just a few days ago, chances are the runtime is not installed there yet. But if you use self-contained apps (deploy framework libraries with your application), then you don't depend on the installed framework

Comment: You're seeing a general error "Something went wrong and your app cant start/run properly" - you'll need to dig into the error logs a bit more to get some help with this really, you should be able to turn on the azure error logging and get something specific; could really be anything hiding behind that message.

Comment: @Tseng I have edited the questions, thanks. How do I know if I'm using portable or self contained? It's ASP.net Core app. Thanks.

Comment: @Russell I tried my best to find the error but wasn't able to find it in azure.

Comment: What do the log files say? (Cloud Explorer -> your subscription > App Services > Log Files? check that logging is enabled (web.config => `stdoutLogEnabled="true`)

Answer (score 29):

Just so it's clear - still something that comes up in ASP.NET Core 2.0 - and as @Techy stated - is in Azure.  Go to Azure, click on your Web App –> "Applications Settings" –> go down to the “App Settings” section and add the “ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT” and “Development”

[image: Azure Portal]

Answer (score 5):

thanks for your comments.
I was able to find error details by adding the following key in application settings in azure portal:
ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT
with value:
Development

I have created a new question regarding the error itself:
[InvalidOperationException: Could not find 'UserSecretsIdAttribute' on assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40704760/invalidoperationexception-could-not-find-usersecretsidattribute-on-assembly)

Thank you

Comment: I guess you ment ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT instead of ASPNET_CORE_ENVIRONMENT

Answer (score 4):

It is a security measure used in production mode so that any user does not got sensitive exception information from our app.

You can change ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT from "Production" to "Development".

Another option is to change the code for the Configure () method in Startup.cs. It is this method makes a validation:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    }

    ...
}
```

It is not recommended, but you can eliminate this condition:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Visually describing where you need to perform this action. I read it many times but took me time to figure out my way. [image]

1. Go to configuration
2. New Application setting
3. Name :  ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT Value: Development