# EF Core 1.1 to WebApi Core - Add-Migration fails

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I think I’ve got all my dependencies running 1.1 properly but when I try to follow the steps here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/new-db I get an error running the Add-Migration command.

***PM> Add-Migration InitialState***

An error occurred while calling method ‘ConfigureServices’ on startup class ‘Startup’.

> Consider using IDbContextFactory to override the initialization of the
> DbContext at design-time. Error: This method could not find a user
> secret ID because the application’s entry assembly is not set. Try
> using the “.AddUserSecrets(Assembly assembly)” method instead.  No
> parameterless constructor was found on ‘ApplicationDbContext’. Either
> add a parameterless constructor to ‘ApplicationDbContext’ or add an
> implementation of ‘IDbContextFactory’ in the same assembly as
> ‘ApplicationDbContext’.

**relevant sections of my project.json:
…**

```
 “Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore”: “1.1.0”,
“Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer”: “1.1.0”,
“Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design”: {
“type “: “build”,
“version”: “1.1.0”
},
“Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools”: “1.1.0-preview4-final”
},

“tools”: {
“Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet”: “1.1.0-preview4-final”
},
```

**My ApplicationDbContext does have the constructor:**

```
public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
 { }
```

**and my Startup.cs does have the:**

```
services.AddDbContext(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString(“DefaultConnection”)));
```

What else can it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternate solution:

I ran into the same problem and landed here. But I am writing an app from scratch comparing it at every step with the DotNetCore WebApp with Individual auth. that gets generated via wizard in VS 2017 hoping to follow latest practices. So it was strange when everything was identical in my code and the generated code and I was getting this exception. The generated code did not have Michael Dennis's suggested code in startup.cs, which does not mean he is wrong, it just means there was now a different way. Upon diving down further I found out that **UserSecretsId** was declared in myprojetname.csproj like follows:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <UserSecretsId>aspnet-mywebproect-006a401f-2fdc-4aad-abb1-12c00000004a</UserSecretsId>
</PropertyGroup>
```

After adding the entry in my project.csproj file, the issue was resolved.

Comment: Thanks Hassan. Yes my above solution was for VS2015. I have recently upgraded my project to VS2017 and putting it in CSPROJ instead of project.json seems to now work so you don't need the attribute anymore.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is related to the `builder.AddUserSecrets()` call. To fix perform the following steps:

1. Adding the user secret to the assembly (instead of just **project.json**) by adding attribute  `[assembly: UserSecretsId("aspnet-TestApp-ce345b64-19cf-4972-b34f-d16f2e7976ed")]` to **Startup.cs**
2. In **Startup.cs** replace `builder.AddUserSecrets()` with `builder.AddUserSecrets<Startup>();`

Reference: [InvalidOperationException: Could not find 'UserSecretsIdAttribute' on assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40704760/invalidoperationexception-could-not-find-usersecretsidattribute-on-assembly/40704864#40704864)

Comment: In the version I am using I could just pass the user secrets string to `builder.AddUserSecrets()` as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is not related to EF Core, it's about [User Secrets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets)

Check your `Startup.cs` constructor - it contains `AddUserSecrets()` call. You can remove it. Later, when you read about User Secrets, you can add it back with correct configuration (I guess you have website template from 1.0.0, while referencing library 1.1.0 - it contains [this bug fix](https://github.com/aspnet/UserSecrets/issues/62))

Comment: Yes was related to the AddUserSecrets(). When I comment out that line I am able to add the migration.

Comment: The bug fix link you provided does not solve the problem, however. If I check for project.json existence (below) the migration still fails.  `if (env.IsDevelopment() && builder.GetFileProvider().GetFileInfo("project.json").Exists) 
            {
                builder.AddUserSecrets();
            }`

Comment: Yes, it will fail because you are returning `AddUserSecrets` :) You should configure it properly. Check https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/209.