# .NET Core IConfigurationRoot with UserSecrets outside of main method

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core

I'm trying to use [user secrets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets) in a console application to store a connection string for my database. It works fine when I set up everything in the `Program.Main` method.

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true)
        .AddUserSecrets();


    var configuration = builder.Build();

    using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))) {
        foreach (var person in db.People) {
            Console.WriteLine($"Person: {person.FirstName}");
        }
    }
}
```

But this requires the `ApplicationDbContext` to take a parameter in the constructor, preventing the `dotnet ef` tools from working. If I try building the configuration in the `ApplicationDbContext` class, I get this error:

```
Could not find 'UserSecretsIdAttribute' on assembly 'ef, Version=1.1.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=...'
```

I thought it might be related to [this issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/issues/543), but adding the `Assembly` argument had no effect.

```
.AddUserSecrets(typeof(Program).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
```

I also tried adding the `UserSecretsId` property in the `xproj`, as [recommended by this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40704760/invalidoperationexception-could-not-find-usersecretsidattribute-on-assembly/40704864#40704864), but it still could not be found. It is already in my `project.json` file as:

```
{
  "userSecretsId": "Project-45654..."
}
```

How can I use user secrets to store the database connection string in my console app and still be able to use the `dotnet ef` command line tools?