# Accessing configuration options in ASP.NET Core: options pattern

Tags: c#, configuration, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core application. I try to use the options pattern but it does not seem to work.

I have the following `appsettings.json`:

```
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "MyTablesConnectionString": "Default[...];EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
    },

    "Logging": { "IncludeScopes": false, "LogLevel": { "Default": "Warning" }  }
}
```

The following `ConnectionStrings` class

```
public class ConnectionStrings {
    public ConnectionStrings()  {
        MyTablesConnectionString = "default value";
    }

    public string MyTablesConnectionString { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my `Startup.cs`

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    Configuration = builder.Build();

    // HERE IS THE GOOD VALUE !!!!!!!!
    Debug.WriteLine($"Connection string is:{Configuration["ConnectionStrings:MyTablesConnectionString"]}");
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Adds services required for using options.
    services.AddOptions();
    // Register the IConfiguration instance which "ConnectionStrings" binds against.
    services.Configure<ConnectionStrings>(Configuration);

    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc();            
}
```

However, when using it on the dev machine with the following controller

```
private readonly ConnectionStrings azureConnectionString;
public HelloWorldController(IOptions<ConnectionStrings> optionsAccessor)
{
    // HERE IS THE "DEFAULT" VALUE ?!!!!!!!!
    azureConnectionString = optionsAccessor.Value;            
}
```

I see that the "default value" instead of the value from the json file (invalid one) is used. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to bind the ConnectionStrings section, like so:

```
services.Configure<ConnectionStrings>(Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings"));
```

At the moment it is expecting to find a property "ConnectionStrings" or "Logging" from your class, since you are binding the root.

Comment: By the way, docs says do not keep the sensitive information like passwords in the json files, in order they do not be achieved with the source code... Where then to keep them? because `MyTablesConnectionString` clearly contains the azure storage key

Comment: I actually wrote a blog article a while back on the different options: https://joonasw.net/view/asp-net-core-1-configuration-deep-dive. Check out user secrets. It allows you to keep things like passwords out of source control.

Comment: Tried to install in my ASP.NET Core solution, but...Error Package 'Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools 1.0.1' has a package type 'DotnetCliTool' that is not supported by project 'MyProject'

Comment: If you are on 1.X, install this one: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets/1.1.2. And if you want the CLI tool, you need to add that to csproj like: `<ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="1.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>`

Comment: ItemGroup didn't work for the Error message above, I installed it via PMC `Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets`. Thanks ! Good Article by the way, exactly what I searched for!

Comment: another thing I don't have any "project.json" in my ASP.NET Core project in Visual Studio 2017, probably I should create one to store `userSecretsId`

Comment: Ahh, no. project.json was the old format. It now goes in the csproj file. You can right-click on the project in solution explorer and click Edit appname.csproj...

Comment: Here's how you can add it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40704864/1658906

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, configure all [options automatically](https://github.com/tchelidze/Register.Options.Asp.Net.Core)

```
PM> Install-Package Register.Options.Asp.Net.Core
```

*Startup.cs*

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.ConfigureOptionsFromAssemblies(configuration, new List<Assembly>()
    {
        typeof(ConnectionStrings).Assembly
    });

   ...
}
```

*Disclaimer author of [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Register.Options.Asp.Net.Core/)*