# .net core mvc project uploading web database error

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

Error.
An error occurred while processing your request.
Request ID: 00-9b679c467ad4ae70c778e88de56c8c7c-e143a80f82aa3911-00

Development Mode
Swapping to Development environment will display more detailed information about the error that occurred.

The Development environment shouldn't be enabled for deployed applications. It can result in displaying sensitive information from exceptions to end users. For local debugging, enable the Development environment by setting the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable to Development and restarting the app.

i get this error when i go to database related page

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since this error page only appears when accessing database-related pages, the problem may be in your database connection or reading, and you need to change to the development environment to read detailed error information.

If you are running your app locally, set `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` to `Development` in the `launchSettings.json` file:

```
"environmentVariables": {
  "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
}
```

If you publish on IIS, please change your `web.config` file. Set `environmentVariables` in `aspNetCore` tag:

```
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MyApp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" >
    <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
    </environmentVariables>
</aspNetCore>
```

If you publish on Azure, you can refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46413899) to set development environment.

You can locate the specific problem based on the detailed error message.